# jQuery MultFile upload disables the upload button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am attempting to use [jQuery Multiple File Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/), but having problems with validation. The file upload control gets disabled after my validation runs, and I can't figure out why. I recreated the bare minimum here to demonstrate the problem.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script language="c#" runat="server">
    protected void validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
</script>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function validate(sender, args)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            //addedd as suggested on the following, but it doesn't work
            //fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Uploading
            $.fn.MultiFile.reEnableEmpty();  
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="attachments" runat="server" class="multi"  />
        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="customValidator" 
                             ErrorMessage="This field is required" 
                             OnServerValidate="validate"
                             ClientValidationFunction="validate" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue are you able to solve it?

Comment: I solved it in a pretty crappy way, just by manually re-enabling it. setTimeout(function () { $(questionNode).find('> .answer > div > .MultiFile-wrap > .multi').removeAttr('disabled');}, 200);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I figured out how to solve this was to re-enable the button manually.
I added the timeout just to make sure everything was done executing before my code ran.

```
setTimeout(function () { $(questionNode).find('> .answer > div > .MultiFile-wrap > .multi').removeAttr('disabled');}, 200);
```